# Proofreading: Estimate the number of misprints continuously when to stop

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation

In the book *Introduction to probability and statistics for engineers and scientists*, the author mentioned that to estimate the number of misprints $N$ on a manuscript based on the errors found by $m$ proofreaders ($m >= 3$), we can perform the following steps (with the assumption that each error is **independently** found by each proofreader with the probability $p_{i}$, $i = 1, 2, ...m$):

> Let $n_{f}$ be the number of errors that are found by at least one proofreader. Because $\frac{n_{f}}{N}$ is the fraction of errors that are found by at least one proofreader, this should approximately equal $1 - \prod_{i=1}^{m}(1-p_{i})$, the probability that an error is found by at least one proofreader.

> Therefore, we have
> $\frac{n_{f}}{N} = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^{m}(1-p_{i})$,

> suggesting that $N \approx \hat{N}$ , where $\hat{N} = \frac{n_{f}}{1 - \prod_{i=1}^{m}(1-p_{i})}$              (7.2.1).

> With this estimate of $N$, we can then reset our estimates of the $p_{i}$ by using

> $p_{i} = \frac{n_{i}}{\hat{N}}$, $i = 1,...,m$              (7.2.2).

> We can then reestimate $N$ by using the new value (Equation 7.2.1). (The estimation need not stop here; each time we obtain a new estimate $\hat{N}$ of $N$ we can use Equation 7.2.2 to obtain new estimates of the $p_{i}$, which can then be used to obtain a new estimate of $N4, and so on.)

So my question is when to know to stop the estimation, like is there any threshold or metric to estimate the accuracy?

Update: Or I guess, maybe the estimation always converges on a large number of estimatates.

Comment: Is it just me, or do the first two sentences not make any sense at all?

Comment: @AndrewZhang Little sense. What are the number of errors found by zero proof readers?

Comment: Question to OP: "this" (is it $n_f/N$?) "should approximately equal $\prod_{i=1}^{m}(1-p_{i})$". A bit later you write $$\frac{n_f}{N}=1-\prod_{i=1}^{m}(1-p_{i})\,.$$ I found enough errors in OP here to stop proofreading.

Comment: You're missing $1-$ in front of that first product.

Comment: That book is available as a PDF online. It's worth reading the entire example (Example $7.2$b in the third edition). An important aspect that you failed to mention is that the proofreaders are assumed to find errors independently with certain probabilities $p_i$. I happen to do proofreading professionally, and that assumption seems wildly unrealistic to me.

Comment: @KurtG. joriki has pointed out the missing text in my question, I've just fixed it.

Comment: I really distrust approximations without lower and/or upper bounds,. The author makes such approximations repeatedly, so I put no trust at all in that algorithm. If that is a fair sample of the author's methodology, I suggest you buy another book.